# How to list all shared devices on local WiFi/LAN Network?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, bonjour, nsnetservice

I want to list all shared devices name which is available on that network by which i use on my device. So that i can know who is using the same internet network. After googling i found that using Bonjor i can do it.  I use NSNetService class to discover the available network by make the instance of class NSNetService using the method " initWithDomain:type:name:port: "
In its argument domain:@"" for zero configuration of Bonjor, type:"_Bonjor._tcp." name:@"" for dynamically allocation and port:0 so that it assigned automatically.
With these arguments its discover devices but only those which is using the same app , I think it is because of service type. But i didn't get what service name i provide this method so that it give me the list of all devices using same network not only those devices which use same app. 
Need help for this. Any help be appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can refer this example given by apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html